# Why have the hyperlinks in Excel 2013 stopped working?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, hyperlink

I have used hyperlinks in an excel spreadsheet for years to connect to photo files of glass collection; over 1000 on one spread sheet alone.  While the spread sheet was open we lost power, and when I returned to it, none of the hyperlinks worked any longer.

I have opened a previous version from another folder, and none of those hyperlinks worked either, which I thought was even more odd.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean don't work? They don't point to the correct location? They open a different location? They don't go anywhere?

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595692/how-do-i-convert-a-column-of-text-urls-into-active-hyperlinks-in-excel - I assume you have the text but they are not functioning as links?

Comment: First determine if it's your account - log in as someone else and try again. If it works, it's something in your account settings. Second, you need to determine if it's the sheets or your Excel.  Get someone else to open the sheets on their computer and see if the links are still there and functioning. As others have suggested, please better explain in what way they 'don't work anymore'.

Comment: The message I get is "Cannot open the specified file."

Answer (score 0):

Check your Excel settings to see if the interpretation of a hyperlink value in a cell should be rendered as regular text or if it should be a live hyperlink.

Go to Options -> Proofing and ensure "Ignore Internet and file addresses" is checked on

Comment: This answer could use more information to be complete. It would be best to avoid assuming all readers will know what state the above mentioned option should be set to, so consider specifying that clearly.